# how can I draw just a part of table line in a table in Latex like shown in the picture?

Tags: tables, line

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
            \caption{Definition of Linear Finite Difference Operators}\label{Table1}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l l c l }
            %baraye naboudan khotute amoudi | ha ro hazf kardim {|c|c|c|c|}%
            \hline & \textcolor{red}{Operators} & \cellcolor{yellow}{Symbol} & Difference Representation  \\ \arrayrulecolor{green} \hline
            $(2.1.9a)$                                                                 & Forward Difference         & \textcolor{blue}{$\Delta$} & $\Delta u_r=u_{r+1}-u_r$   \\

            $(2.1.9b)$                                                                 & Backward Difference        & $\nabla $                  & $\nabla u_r=u_r - u_{r-1}$ \\ \arrayrulecolor{black}\hline
        \end{tabular}

    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Thanks a lot for posting a complete MWE. Your title mentions a picture, could you add it to the question? Or simply precise what you're trying to achieve, and what is not working.

Comment: Do you want `\cline{}`? It allows a line to only go across certain columns that can be specified. However, it is horizontal.